# What does "CMV" in "CMV hypothesis" stand for?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, terminology, planescape

While reading some of the archives of the [Mimir.Net](https://mimir.net/files/index.html) mailing list I encountered the "CMV Hypothesis". In short, it says:

> Under the CMV hypothesis, Eladrin, Guardinals, Asuras, and Aasimar
>   are all one race; Aasimon and Archons are not. [Galen, 1999 archive part 3]

After reading several posts about this hypothesis, I still can't figure out what 'CMV' is supposed to stand for. Web searching is confounded by a biology hypothesis of the same name.

So what does the "CMV" in "CMV hypothesis" stand for?

Comment: Good writing practices would have defined any initialization or acronym (there is a difference) on first use.

Comment: @Slagmoth OTOH, this is a mailing list, not an essay.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Celestial, Mortal Variant

You can find the full planescape mailing list archive at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/wotc_mailing_list_archive-2014-01-29). In it, there is an email from author Galen, dated 16 Nov 1999. It goes:

> It is proposed that the Eladrin and the Guardinals are subgroupings of a single race, herein termed CMVs.

The next day, author Doug Meerschaert comments:

> CMV?  Wow... an acronym that he doesn't bother telling what it means... "Celesitally Mortal Vehicles?" (sic)

To which, author Michael Truman answers, the day after:

> Mentioned in the original CMV post - Celestial, Mortal Variant.

---

It appears that the hypothesis assumes that celestials are initially mortals, who die and get re-incarnated as Coure, remain in that stage for 50 to 500 years, and eventually advance to some Mature form. Depending on which plane a CMV is in its Coure form, its Mature form becomes a type of Eladrin, Guardinal, or Asuras.

Comment: How did you find that?! +1

Comment: ooh, I was looking to find a more complete mailing list archive as well, but I neglected to consider archive.org. Well-searched!

Comment: I used to be a member of REALMS-L many years ago and I knew it was a large list. So I first googled for its archive, hoping to track PLANESCAPE-L after it.